# Laravel: Adding 'lowest' attribute to an Eloquent collection

Tags: php, laravel

I have a query returning offers by a given key. This is all functioning well, but I need my application to add a custom key which tells the frontend which offer is the lowest of them all (in price).

How do I achieve this?

My current query:

```
$offers = Offer::with('user:id,fname', 'review')
        ->where('isbn', $isbn)
        ->where('match_id', null)
        ->orderBy('price', 'ASC')
        ->paginate(5);
```

Comment: with this query you already know that the first element of the collection is the lowest

Comment: I'm using pagination, which makes the first element of the collection different on different queries, thus pages. I need a fixed statement to indicate a result is the lowest.